# PHP - Wrong Sum Result

Tags: php, sum

I just have a problem with a sum in php.
My data are :

```
$t = array('-100.80',
'-0.01',
'-7.99',
'-108.00',
'-10.80',
'-34.90',
'-10.80',
'-18.80',
'-17.80',
'-19.50',
'-33.60',
'-32.10',
'-27.50',
'-40.30',
'-31.20',
'-10.60',
'-27.50',
'-120.00',
'-130.00',
'100.80',
'0.01',
'7.99',
'108.00',
'10.80',
'34.90',
'10.80',
'18.80',
'17.80',
'19.50',
'33.60',
'32.10',
'27.50',
'40.30',
'31.20',
'10.60',
'27.50',
'120.00',
'130.00');
```

Total is normally 0 but if i execute an array_sum i just have :

> -5.6843418860808E-14

If i add manually with floatVal() i just have the same result.

Could you explain me why i don't have 0 in result ?

Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Because floating point math.

Comment: As the duplicate says, floating point is leaving a large decimal number. Therefore, if you use `number_forma` and change to 2 dp, you will get 0.  `echo number_format(array_sum($t), 2 );`